# How do I make a character that has a profession besides their class?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation

I was mainly just wondering this since there are some characters I want to create, but the classes don't always fit the idea.

Comment: Is there a specific profession for which you were looking?

Comment: When I went on an npc character generator (I'm running a short campaign for my brother) I came across a lot of professions. One was doctor and another messenger, ect... I was more just wondering how would one go about actually creating a character like that if they didn't want to rely on a class. But they wanted a profession. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Where is this generator? Was it for DnD5E or another system?

Comment: http://npcgenerator.azurewebsites.net/    This one is one my group and I use.

Comment: Are you trying to run a campaign where the player is primarily a doctor (for example), instead of being a classic adventurer (going into dungeons, stopping villians, etc)?

Comment: Yeah. I want to run a character where they aren't a class, but rather have a profession. But if one of my players would want to do it, I want to be able to help them create a character who's not just based on a class.

Comment: Are you the GM or a player? I ask because this is outside the normalcy of the system (at least for players) and would require their approval and for them to do a bit of house ruling to make this work.

Comment: I am GM right now. But this isn't necessarily for any game. But more, I want to know how to do this so if my players want that option.

Comment: I think if we can narrow this down to **Create an NPC with a professional background/skills** vs **Create a homebrew 'class' that is a professional**, this can be answered and opened. The former is very stackable, the latter is not (until you have a homebrewed professional class that can be reviewed for balance.)

Answer (score 7):

### This is typically glossed over with the use of skills, tools and backgrounds.

For example, if you had proficiency in Smith's Tools you were likely some sort of craftsman or at least apprenticed to be so eventually. This would be sort of Guild Artisan background (although I don't particularly care for the naming). You get a tool proficiency as part of the background. This would mean that you could be a smith, woodcarver, alchemist, herbalist and so on.

Folk Hero even has some text on this:

> You previously pursued a simple profession among the peasantry,
>   perhaps as a farmer, miner, servant, shepherd, woodcutter, or
>   gravedigger.

### Import Option

In order for a PC to actually be a Doctor instead of a Cleric that has proficiency in Healer's Kit you will have to figure out a way to give balanced ability on par with PC classes from the book. Especially, if you have both classes and non-classes in the same group.

This is akin to old NPC classes from Dungeons and Dragons 3.0 and 3.5 (specifically the Expert) though and you could do some work on converting these to work in 5E. In any event you will have to design level progression and balance the abilities, all in all it will take a lot of work. It is worth noting that the NPC classes were less powerful than full PC classes.

This option has the advantage of being able to have this PC advance with the rest of the party, albeit being a bit weaker than the norm.

### Something that sort of already exists.

Another option is to use the NPCs from the Monster Manual and add skill proficiencies as needed. These are not really designed to level up and usually are much, much weaker than a standard PC and many would even be non-combatants but not necessarily useless.

Options include starting with Commoner, Guard, Scout or even Spy.

### Caution

If you create something like this and the result is a character that is somewhat weaker than the system is balanced to handle you will be required to tweak existing encounters in published modules to compensate. Unless, of course you are going for a Cthulhu or Dark Souls style horror/suspense feel.

Comment: But would there be a way to simply have a "profession" besides a class? I know there's some in the backgrounds, but if I have a player who wants to be a doctor or messenger, how could they go about it? Those are more professions than classes. I was just wondering and I hope that makes sense. I can't word it right. I'm sorry.

Comment: @Hannah I have added a bit to this with other options. You might address the other questions in the comments under your query as well. If you like several of us could workshop the question in a chat.